# Android-Firebase Database query working very slowly

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am having very much low performance for querying data from database. I have over 200 user nodes. And each nodes have a arraylist. I want to check the number of children available under a specific user node. Here is my code for that i have written.

```
private DatabaseReference root,IdUser;
root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContactList");
IdUser = root.child(userId);
try {

        IdUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                if (count>amount){
                    button.setText("Get Data");
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }else if (count<amount){
                    button.setText("Sync Data");
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }else {
                    button.setText("Sync Data");
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now problem is, it's taking over 1 minutes to get the children count. Please suggest any improvements i can do with my code to increase the query performance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on how much data you have under `/ContactList/$uid` for that user, and what bandwidth the device has that you're retrieving it on.

By definition this is going to be slower than necessary, since you're retrieving the actual contacts instead of just the count.

Consider keeping a separate `contactCount` value for each user somewhere in the database that you update each time you update the contact list for that user.  While this takes more code when you're updating the data, reading just he count now becomes a breeze.